# Generate return type signature in Scala with Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

While Scala has a type inference, it is considered good practice to explicitly define the return type of public functions. Is it possible to get IDEA add the explicit return type from the inferred one?

Comment: I usually write the type signatures for all but the simplest functions as I go so I've never tried, but I don't think the functionality exists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are on a method name then you can hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to get the Intention Actions where the first is usually the <kbd>Add type annotation to function definition</kbd>

Illustration:

[image: Pressing Alt+Enter on a method]

In this case it would add `Int` to the return type of the `exampleFunction`.

Might I add this also works for `val`/`var` declarations, essentially whenever there is a type inferred.

Comment: any idea how to get Intellij to do this for a whole file/package/project ?

Comment: No, I don't think IntelliJ supports that.